# Disabling Re-routing of vehicles when running Veins Example Scenario

Tags: omnet++, veins

Dears,
   These days I am doing a research secnario with Veins. As a first step, I am going to run the example veins scenario with vehicles re-rerouting option and without re-routing when accidents happen. Is this possible? Will it possible with configurations change? Anyway accidents(nodes getting stopped) needs to happen in both scenarios.

Thanks,
Rakkesh

Answer (score 0):

To disable cars' rerouting you can comment out line https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.4/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc#L54 but to make this configurable, you will need to implement an .ini parameter yourself.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. I will check.